# Как изменять цвета фона в textbox в зависимости от значения?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

На форме есть CheckListBox1, в котором несколько строк (фамилий сотрудников). А также на форме есть несколько TextBox-ов (TextBox1, TextBox2, ...). С помощью определенных кнопок в TextBox-ы заносятся данные.
Есть класс, описывающий человека (он содержит имя и по одному свойству привязанному к соответствующему textBox-у):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    //...равное количеству TextBox-ов.
}
```

Есть коллекция в которой хранятся сотрудники.

```
BindingList<Person> people = new BindingList<Person>();
```

Коллекция привязана к CheckListBox1:

```
var listBox = ((ListBox)CheckListBox1);
listBox.DataSource = people;
listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

TextBox-ы привязаны к коллекции:

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", people, "Value1", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
...
```

В итоге данные введённые в TextBox-ы заносятся в свойства человека.
Вопрос: Как по аналогии с Value1, Value2, ... выставлять и запоминать цвет фона TextBox-а в зависимости от его значения, например, если в TextBox введено значение "2", то окрасить в зеленый цвет, если "К2" - в желтый и т.д. Делать цвет фона как еще одно свойство или просто процедурой окраски фона?

*(winforms c# vs2010 net 4.0)*

Comment: Если я правильно понял принцип работы `DataBindings`, то можно в свой класс добавить свойства, которые хранят значения цвета, в коде написать логику по заданию этим свойствам значений и биндить `TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Background", people, "Color1", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Код формы

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<Person> _people = new BindingList<Person>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetBindings();
        LoadData();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        var clb = _checkedListBoxPeople as ListBox;
        clb.DataSource = _people;
        clb.DisplayMember = "Name";

        //привязка к текст. свойству
        _textBoxValue.DataBindings.Add("Text", _people, "Value");
        //привязка к цвету фона через метод конвертер
        Binding bValueColor = new Binding("BackColor", _people, "Value");
        bValueColor.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(IntToBackColor);
        _textBoxValue.DataBindings.Add(bValueColor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Метод конвертирующий целочисл. значение в значение цвета
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void IntToBackColor(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DesiredType != typeof(Color)) return;

        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Value) == 1)
        {
            e.Value = Color.Azure;
            return;
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Value) > 1)
        {
            e.Value = Color.Wheat;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Value = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        _people.Add(new Person { Name = "Иванов", Value = 1 });
        _people.Add(new Person { Name = "Петров", Value = 2 });
        _people.Add(new Person { Name = "Сидоров", Value = 3 });
        _people.Add(new Person { Name = "Григорьев", Value = 0 });
    }   
}
```

Comment: сколько времени потребуется человеку из тех.поддержки, который видит все это в первый раз и не очень понимает для чего вообще была написана программа, чтобы въехать в Ваш "модерн" и мой "прошлый век" :). Чем меньше наворочено тем лучше, но все равно "+" от меня.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов спасибо, за оценку, сделаю взаимной. А `Binding` не какой не модерн. Если я правильно помню, то привязки появились в WinForms во второй версии .Net Framwork. Только беда их в том, что про них почему-то писали в книгах мало или совсем не писали, и на курсах тоже вообще ничего не говорили.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Подскажите пожалуйста, "привязку к цвету фона через метод конвертер" нужно очищать, типа "textBoxValue.DataBindings.Clear();", например, при добавлении новой фамилии (после чтения данных) и дальнейшей перепривязке?

Comment: @olga в принципе привязки после создания можно/лучше не менять, а менять содержимое источника данных, т.е. `BindingList<Person> _people` вот в него вы можете добавлять, удалять людей и `BindingList` будет оповещать `ListBox` об изменении состава отображаемой коллекции.

Comment: @olga если вам очень нужно вы конечно можете очищать привязку и заново ее создавать, но зачем? Тогда теряется весь смысл работы с привязками. Они и созданы для того, чтоб единожды создав их, вы дальше изменяли бы только источник данных для них, т.е. в нашем случае `BindingList<Person>`. `BindingList<T>` тем и отличается от обычного `List<T>` что оповещает привязанные к нему контролы об изменении в составе коллекции и, если вы в классе модели реализуете `INotifyPropertyChanged`, еще об изменении свойств экземпляра модели.

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите пожалуйста события "bValueColor.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(IntToBackColor);" засоряют память? надо при выходе из программы "чистить" (их получается несколько -на каждый textbox)?

Answer (score 2):

К каждому TextBox-у добавляете обработчик на изменение текста

```
           this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

Это лучше сделать средствами средствами дизайнера форм на закладке "Events".

В обработчик вставляете код вроде этого

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "1")
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        if (textBox1.Text == "2")
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.Coral;
        if (textBox1.Text == "3")
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.Cyan;

    }
```

Comment: Автор вопроса работает правильно - через привязки. А вы предлагаете вернуться к примитивности прямого взаимодействия с контролами и их значениями через события, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: @Bulson Напишите свой вариант - мой примитивен, но гарантировано работает :). Не все старое плохо. Нужно думать о сопровождении программы и не перегружать классы, ответственные за бизнес-логику (класс описывающий человека) подробностями о цвета фона в TextBox-ах.